# Why do CSS Grid items not start on new rows at max columns?

Tags: css, css-grid

I have been trying to crack CSS Grids for the past couple of days. For some reason, I cannot get the grip of it.

So, I make columns and set rows as auto. When I have content that reaches the 12th row, content does not automatically move onto a new row. Am I miss understanding something here?

I see some example of;

```
grid-column: 1/1
grid-row: 1/1
```

But I do not want to do it this way and would prefer using pixels etc.

Honestly, I think I've lost hair follicles trying to figure this out.

Any help is appreciated.

```
.grid-container {  
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 150px auto;
  column-gap: 10px;
  row-gap: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;}

.grid1, .grid2,
.grid3, .grid4,
.grid5, .grid6,
.grid7, .grid8,
.grid9, .grid10,
.grid11, .grid12 {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;}

.grid1{
  width: 70px}
.grid2{
  width: 150px}
.grid3{
  width: 230px}
.grid4{
  width: 310px}
.grid5{
  width: 390px}
.grid6{
  width: 470px}
.grid7{
  width: 550px}
.grid8{
  width: 630px}
.grid9{
  width: 710px}
.grid10{
  width: 790px}
.grid11{
  width: 870px}
.grid12{
  width: 950px}
```

Answer (score 0):

Written with good intentions, there are a few red flags in the properties you've specified which suggest you may want to do a brush up on your core CSS as well as understanding the grid.

But, to your direct question: why aren't you starting to see items move into the next row?

That's because you have 12 items in your grid and you gave those items 12 columns per row with your property:

`grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);`

If you give 12 columns to 12 grid items then they have exactly enough space to live in one row of the grid.

For your continuing practice, change the line I identified above to

`grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);`

You'll see the following: 12 elements divided into a 2 column grid is 6 rows. The first row is 150px height per your specification, and the other rows are auto (i.e. fit exactly to the size of the div contents.

[image: 12 elements in a 2 column grid]

I hope this helps you along your way.